# Why isn't there any $t$ in the discrete version of CDF?

Tags: probability, random-variables

See the image from the book of [Seymour Lipschutz](http://www.uobabylon.edu.iq/eprints/publication_6_26155_6153.pdf), Page-$85$.

[image]

**I haven't understood the above.**

If $x$ represents the values of the random variable $X$. Then $f(x)$ is the density function for $X$.

So, if we compare this with the discrete version,

[image]

The continuous version seems different. I am especially curious about $t$.

$1$. Why isn't there any $t$ in the discrete version?

$2$. Shouldn't there have been $x$ in the place of $t$, and $t$ in the place of $x$?

$3$. What would be the **CDF** for the below problem?

> A cow can produce $5$ to $10$ liters of milk per day.
>
> What is the probability that the cow will produce:
>
> $(1)$ exactly $7.5$ liters of milk next day?
>   $(2)$ at most $7.5$ liters of milk next day?
>   $(3)$ at least $7.5$ liter of milk next day?
>
> **Note:** say, consider the distribution as a sine wave.

**Edit:**

[image]

Comment: The $t$ in the integral is just a "dummy variable" of integration. You could replace $t$ in the integral with basically anything (like $u,\theta,s,\xi$) and nothing will change. For example, $\int_{-\infty}^{x}f(t)\, dt$ is the same thing as $\int_{-\infty}^{x}f(u)\, du$. The reason that the upper limit of the integral is $\color{blue}x$ is that we are finding $\Pr(X\le \color{blue}{x})$ ($x$ is like some particular number we want to find the probability of $X$ being less than or equal to).

Comment: @MinusOne-Twelfth, more important question is, what does $t$ represent in the above picture?

Comment: In the above picture, $t$ is the variable for the horizontal axis of the graph. However, it doesn't matter what label we use (i.e. as I said, we could replace $t$ by $u$ or $\alpha$ or whatever; the area under the PDF doesn't depend on what we call the horizontal axis variable).

Comment: You could argue that the "$x_i$" in the sum in your second screenshot is analogous to the $t$ in the integral.

Comment: Great! If one of you guys could write up an answer below, that would be awesome. We don't like to have questions answered completely in the comments.

Comment: @MinusOne-Twelfth, in the discrete case, horizontal axis was $x$. Isn't that so?